# Why my Aspect is not detected for Jersey controller (using custom annotation)?

Tags: java, jersey, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I want to create an Aspect over a Jersey controller to measure how long the services take to be executed. I'm fighting against my pointcut since it isn't detected and my aspect never gets launched.

I have tried using lots of pointcuts like:

```
execution(@Monitor * *.*(..))
execution(public * *(..))
change the order of @Aspect and @Component

Added a pointcut like this:
@Pointcut("execution(@Monitor * *.*(..))")
public void monitorRequestTargets(){}
@Around("monitorRequestTargets()")

Tried using AOP and CGLIB
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>

Also tried changing the order of configuration in context.xml
```

Eclipse detects that my methods are being adviced by my aspect but it isn't executed at runtime. Could you give me any hint about why aspect is not created or the pointcut doesn't launch?

My code is the following.

**Context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Enables AspectJ -->
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

    <!-- .....more definitions -->

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mypackage" />

</beans:beans>
```

My **MonitorAspect**

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class MonitorAspect
{
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MonitorAspect.class);

    @Around("@annotation(com.mypackage.Monitor)")
    public void logTimeUsage(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable 
    {
        // Store executing method
        String method = joinPoint.getSignature().getName();

        // Track time
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        joinPoint.proceed();
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        long duration = endTime - startTime;

        // Log time consumed by executing method
        logger.info(method + ": " + duration);

    }
}
```

My Monitor custom annotation is

```
@Target(value = {ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Monitor
{

}
```

My controller which I want to use the aspect:

```
    @Monitor
    @POST
    @Consumes("application/json")
    @Produces("application/json")
    @Path("/{tkn}/test/")
    public Response test(
            @Context HttpServletRequest httpReq,
            @Context UriInfo uri,
                     String enrollReqJson
            ) {
          Thread.sleep(1000); // Implementation is not important
    }
```

My **pom.xml**

```
<!-- Spring -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
</dependency>
  <!-- Jersey / Spring -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-spring</artifactId>
    <version>1.14</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
</dependency>
        <!-- Spring AOP / AspectJ -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
    <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
    <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Is your controller in the com.mypackage package?

Comment: whatever Kyle mentions as well as     @Around(value = "@annotation(com.mypackage.Monitor)"). Try this. Is your Aspect also scanned during the component scan?

Comment: Also, an around Advice should return an Object, it cannot be void

Comment: Let's see your full controller class.

Comment: @Hrishikesh, how can I check if my aspect is scanned at component scan?

Comment: @Kyle, my controller class is under com.mypackage like all the classes

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, my controller is in the package com.mypackage.controller and the class has \@Component annotation

Comment: @Fede When i say if it is component scanned, what i mean is is does it exist in this below package. If it does, it will be loaded during the appcontext creation    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mypackage" />

Comment: What implementation of JAX-RS are you using? Do you have the appropriate Spring integration JARs on the classpath?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, I'm using 
<org.springframework-version>3.1.1.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
<org.aspectj-version>1.6.9</org.aspectj-version>

Comment: `@Path` is a JAX-RS annotation. Are you using jersey?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, yes in the project we're using jersey

Comment: You need a Spring-jersey integration jar which will make Jersey use your Spring beans instead of instantiating them itself. Are you doing this?

Comment: I think so, in our pom.xml we have <artifactId>jersey-spring</artifactId><version>1.14</version>. But after looking at this entries it has an exclusion list where spring-aop is appearing. Could it be the issue?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, any idea?

Comment: Post your pom.xml, I'll take a look.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, done, just edited the post

Comment: Try the following: create a no-arg constructor in your controller class with a simple log statement. Check how many times that log statement is printed.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, I've already have a no-arg constructor. Checked how many times it is run and it runs 3 times when I start the server, then anymore.

Comment: It seems to me that at least one of those is probably advised by your Aspect (therefore managed by Spring), but the one handling the requests is managed by Struts. I don't know Struts integration with Spring at all, so I recommend you investigate how those two work together.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, it could be but I start the server in debug mode the aspect never stops at breakpoints. I'm not sure but I feel that there could be a problem over jersey, aspect and spring. It is like the aspect is completely by passed by the component scanning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found why my aspects weren't working with Jersey because I had to use the weaver for this particular case.

After configuring aspectj-maven-plugin to weave my aspects everything works successfully.

The full details to configure the weaver can be found on this answer:
[Spring + AspectJ weaving for java 8 using aspectj-maven-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25209339/spring-aspectj-weaving-for-java-8-using-aspectj-maven-plugin)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the same problem I was having. Based on what you've provided, it looks like you're using Spring AOP on an object that is not created by Spring (presumably Jersey is what creates your controller class instances) and therefore the advice is not being applied. Eclipse says its being advised, but that would only be for instances of your controller that are created by Spring. The ones you are actually using, the ones created by Jersey (or whatever provider you are using), are not advised.

I spent a lot of time trying to get Jersey to use Spring to create controller instances (including a couple of plugins that claimed to be able to do just that), but never could get it to work. I was able to get it working by using AspectJ directly instead of Spring AOP. It wasn't very hard, with exception of figuring out how to get spring to inject into the aspect.

Added:

The annotations remain the same. You just need to remove the AOP stuff from spring.xml, and create an aop.xml file in META-INF. Here's what mine looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE aspectj PUBLIC "-//AspectJ//DTD//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/dtd/aspectj.dtd">
<aspectj>
    <aspects>
        <aspect name="com.ancestry.academy.api.ServiceApiAspect" />
        <aspect name="com.ancestry.academy.manager.ManagerApiAspect" />
    </aspects>
</aspectj>
```

You can keep Spring AOP for classes that are spring loaded. You only have to do this for classes that are created outside of spring (like controllers for jax).

There's one little piece of black magic that I don't really understand. If you need to use spring to inject into your aspect itself, then you need to declare it in spring.xml like this:

```
<bean id="serviceApiAspect" class="com.ancestry.academy.api.ServiceApiAspect" factory-method="aspectOf" />

<bean id="managerApiAspect" class="com.ancestry.academy.manager.ManagerApiAspect" factory-method="aspectOf" />
```

Note that my aspects do NOT have a method named aspectOf. Apparently that's added by AspectJ. That was pretty much all there was to it.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I understand your point but don't understand why spring doesn't handle the aspect if I've annotated it with @Component. By the way, if you are right, you could please add an example of using AspectJ instead of SpringAOP? Thanks a lot

Comment: It has to do with who creates it. If its annotated with @Component, then spring will create an instance that it can use. If Jersey creates the instance, then spring doesn't have an opportunity to proxy it. Unfortunately, the instance you really care about is the one that Jersey creates.

Comment: thanks for the comment. Do you know how I can do it with spring? Or a way to create an aspect to reach Jersey objects?

Comment: thanks very much for your answer definitely +1. I'll try your code. As soon as I test it I'll let you know and of couse if it works will chose your answer as correct.

Comment: I've tried your suggestions and more but couldn't make it work. I tried matching every public method and the aspect gets loaded but never enter in my Jersey controller.

Answer (score 0):

add

```
compile 'org.aspectj:aspectjtools:1.8.1'
compile 'org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.8.1'
```

make annotation

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface ParmsAudit
{
  String action();
}
```

aspect class

```
@Aspect
public class AuditAspect {

@Before(value="execution(@uk.co.billcomer.audit.ParmsAudit * *(..)) &&   @annotation(parmsAudit)", argNames="parmsAudit")
public void logTheAuditActivity(JoinPoint aPoint, ParmsAudit parmsAudit) {
 String userName = getUserName();
 mlogger.info("Parms Auditing User Name: " + userName);
 mlogger.info("auditType:" + parmsAudit.auditType().getDescription());

 String arguments = getArgs(aPoint.getArgs());

 if (arguments.length() > 0) {
 mlogger.info("args-" + arguments);
 }
}

private String getArgs(Object[] args) {
 String arguments = "";
 int argCount = 0;

 for (Object object : args) {
   if (argCount > 0) {
     arguments += ", ";
   }
   arguments += "arg[" + ++argCount + "]=" + "[" + object + "]";
 }
 return arguments;
}

private String getUserName() {
 try {
   return SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();
 } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
   return "Unknown User";
 }
}
}
```

This is nice link http://billcomer.blogspot.in/2011/07/auditing-using-aop-and-annotations-in.html