# Migration from java 7 to java 8

Tags: java, maven, java-8, aspectj-maven-plugin

I have migrated my app from java 7 to java 8 but pom.xml build fails because of aspectj-maven complier. I have tried till 1.7 version but no luck.

Please provide aspectj-maven-plugin support for java 8. I have used till 1.7 but its not working.

Comment: Are you expecting that a Maven plugin developer is now going to do it or something?

Comment: There is already an answer for this problem here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25209339/spring-aspectj-weaving-for-java-8-using-aspectj-maven-plugin

Comment: When I run the existing pom.xml with JAVA 8 it showing following exception  Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12:test

Comment: @ Vyncent : Yes I have did that. But it showing Error injecting: org.codehaus.mojo.aspectj.AjcCompileMojo
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: [Lorg/codehaus/plexus/util/Scanner;
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
 at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.getInjectionPoints(InjectionPoint.java:674)

Comment: Spring + AspectJ weaving for java 8 using aspectj-maven-plugin  is not working